# Getting A Specific Twitter Status

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to get the contents of a specific status using the status url e.g http://twitter.com/#!/jquery/status/36102693709680640 and also get the username associated with the status.  In this case, @jquery

Is there a way to do this in php and/or jquery?

Comment: Would scraping the data via PHP be an option?

Comment: yes, but that should work for all status links...

Comment: Hadn't used the Twitter API before so didn't know if you could use it - Chuck's answer below is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage). You must perform an HTTP request on the correct URI and the data will be returned in XML format. You'll then parse the XML for the needed data.

The twitter username is under the`screen_name` tag.